# Using Parse Cloud Code in Conjunction with .NET SDK

Tags: c#, javascript, ios, .net, parse-platform

Objective:

- When a table is updated with a new row (ParseFile + ParseUser + ParseUser), send one of the ParseUsers a push notification
- When a new user is created, add a new row to a table (ParseFile + user)

Can either of these be easily achieved without jumping through some major hoops? I'm completely unfamiliar with Cloud Code, though I tried to read through some of the documentation. Cloud Code looks like it has the potential to perform this task, but I haven't seen any examples of doing something like I would like to do.

Does anyone have concrete examples of using Parse Cloud Code in conjunction with the .NET SDK and table updates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse has a nice Documentation: [Parse CloudCode](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-onsave)

This is an example Code, which sends a push every time a user is created

```
//instead of Parse.User you can use any custom parse class too, but write them inside quotes
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function(request) {
    if(!request.object.existed()){//existed() returns false if the object was just created
        var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
        query.equalTo("User", request.object);
        Parse.Push.send({
            where: query,
            data: {
                badge: "Increment",
                alert: "Welcome " + request.object.get("username"),
                sound: "beep.caf"
            }
        }, {
            success: function(){
                //succeed
            },
            error: function(err){
                console.error("Got an error " + error.code + " : " + error.message);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

There are also other hooks available:

- [beforeSave](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-modifysave)
- [afterSave](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-aftersave)
- [beforeDelete](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-ondelete)
- [afterDelete](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-afterdelete)

Inside these hooks you can send push notifications, create new objects, manipulate objects, do nearly whatever you want.

In Parse CloudCode you can take advantage of the [Parse JavaScript API](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#javascript_guide).